# Unable to run Cypress Cucumber tests. Receving weird Gherkin error

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

When I try to run my cucumber tests with Cypress using the @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, I get this weird error:[image]

This is indicating that the error is coming from my `duckduckgo.feature` file which is as follows:

```html
Scenario Outline: Steps will run conditionally if tagged
  
  When user visits <site>
  Then <site> search bar will display

  @google
  Examples:
    | site                  |
    | google.com            |

  @duckduckgo
  Examples:
    | site                   |
    | duckduckgo.com         |
```

Here is my `cypress.config.js` file:

```html
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const browserify = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));

  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
  
});
```

Seems like Cypress isn't recognizing my step definitions or my test but I'm not sure why. Everything was working perfectly until a few days ago. I've tried using other bundlers but with no luck. Kind of just pluggin in random things and praying at this point. Can anyone decipher this error?

[Here](https://github.com/caseycling/cukey) is the repo if you want to tinker around with it.

Comment: The screenshot is almost impossible to read on a small screen. Please copy paste error messages.

Comment: Your feature file should start with `Feature: Some name `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start your Feature file with "Feature:" + name of feature.
I recommend you using one of Feature formatter which will format feature files according to standards (Feature Syntax Highlight and Snippets, feature-file, BDD - Feature-Editor etc.)